# Source Generator: information about referencing project?

Tags: c#, code-generation, sourcegenerators

I started playing with the C# source generators.

What I want is to kick off a `git describe --tags --long` process and populate a static `GitVersion` class with the current tag and hash code as properties.

The problem is, that I have no information about the directory of the referencing project so I cannot know where to run the git process.
I cannot find any useful information in the `GeneratorExecutionContext` argument of the `Execute` function.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain` points to the csc.exe process so I guess there is no way to know it's there?

Answer (score 9):

I ended up using:

```
public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context) {
     var mainSyntaxTree = context.Compilation.SyntaxTrees
                          .First(x => x.HasCompilationUnitRoot);

     var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(mainSyntaxTree.FilePath);
```

Comment: Note that this only works in case there is a .cs file compiled at the root of the project. Otherwise the mainSyntaxTree will not point to the csproj directory.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you could not get the reference project directory from `GeneratorExecutionContext`, but you can pass the path information by manually specifying the meta of `.csproj`, then retrieve the path meta in generating time.

Comment: Is there an example of how this can be done? It's a bit difficult to visualize this into an implementation from your recommendation. Thanks

Comment: @Andrew: I found an easier way as shown below.

Comment: context.AnalyzerConfigOptions.GlobalOptions
            .TryGetValue("build_property.MSBuildProjectDirectory", 
                     out var projectDirectory);

Comment: I think the magic string has changed to "build_property.projectdir".

Comment: It works for me with @Peter's property name.