# Add non-C# files in source generators

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

I'm creating a source generator that creates Typescript utilities based on user C# code, right now the only efficient way to create a file is `AddSource()` method, which can **only** create `*.cs` files.

I need to create `*.ts` files (or `*.js`), using `File.Write*` is also a pain, because the path and referencing project are unknown (`Environment.CurrentDirectory` will return the generator path which is not even close to user project) to generator, currently the only way to find the path is:

```cs
var baseFilePath = context.Compilation.SyntaxTrees.First(x => x.HasCompilationUnitRoot).FilePath;

var myDir = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(baseFilePath)!, "tsFiles");
```

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66548212/15204250).

which as you can see is not really nice and safe and it would be a performance killer since it cannot be used in `Initialize` method, it has to be in `Execute` method which will execute forever and you have to either put an if statement to check `File.Exists()` or it will create that file for ever.

Considering all these, what is the most efficient way to create non-C# files (both in startup and execution time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For either a ISourceGenerator or IIncrementalGenerator, you should be able to access the target project's "build_property.projectdir" value from AnalyzerConfigOptions.

The following is a gist that I use for the same thing in an IIncrementalGenerator.

```
IncrementalValueProvider<string?> projectDirProvider = context.AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider
    .Select(static (provider, _) => { 
        provider.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue("build_property.projectdir", out string? projectDirectory);

        return projectDirectory;
});
   

context.RegisterSourceOutput(
    projectDirProvider, 
    static (context, source) => {
    
    string? projectDirectory = source;

});
```

This will give you the base/root directory of your target project and from there you should be able to use System.IO for what you need.